# Audio play on hover / mouse over, possible without jQuery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, hover

I just put together this code to play audio on hover.. on a test page, trying to incorporate it into the rest of the site, but the jQuery is clashing with other jQuery, and noconflict mode at this point is a pretty huge job. Is it possible to do the following using only javascript ?

```
<audio id="whiterose"  preload="auto">
                <source src="//sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/white-rose.mp3"></source>
                <source src="//sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/white-rose.ogg"></source>
</audio>


<div class="whiterose">

<a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk">white rose?</a>

</div>

<script>

//change audio 1 to audio 2.. 3 .. etc

var audioOne = $("#whiterose")[0];
$(".whiterose a")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        audioOne.play();
    });


</script>
```

http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio.html#

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<audio id="audio"  preload="auto" src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/white-rose.mp3"></audio>
<div id="test" style="background-color:red;" class="whiterose">
    <a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk">white rose?</a>
</div>

<script>
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan ! And it only seems to be working if you click in blank space before hovering, is there a way around this ?

Comment: Chrome is blocking video and audio autoplay since version 66, the error is: “Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first”." you can find some posts about it here, but i think there's no workaround